# sql: How to find the max length of consecutive sequence of given char in a string using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

let the char be `s` and string be `mississsipisssss` . The sql should return 5.

I was thinking to makeup something using

`regexp_count(string,'s+')` would return the number of substrings whith consecutive sequence of `s` .

`REGEXP_INSTR(string,'s',1,m)` would return the position of the m'th occurence of char `s`(starting position of mth sequence)

`REGEXP_INSTR(string,'s[^s]',1,m)` would return the position of the m'th occurence of char `s` (ending position of mth sequence)

I havent still come to any solution.But I dont think this is a correct way,as the strings could be of any length, and there could be any number of such consecutive sequences. Could someone give any idea for solution (I am beginner)

Answer (score 1):

This will work in sql-server 2008 +.  The same concept will work in Oracle you just need to add a couple of syntax differences such as SUBSTR instead of SUBSTRING.  Here is a quick attempt of converting to Oracle syntax:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable
    (String VARCHAR(100)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TempTable (String) VALUES ('mississsipisssss');
INSERT INTO #TempTable (String) VALUES ('ssasdfs');

WITH cteTokens (String, IndexNum, Token, CharCount) AS  (
    SELECT
       String
       ,1 as IndexNum
       ,SUBSTR(t.String,1,1) as Token
       ,CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.String,1,1) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As CharCount
    FROM
       #TempTable t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.String
       IndexNum + 1 as IndexNum
       ,SUBSTR(t.String,IndexNum + 1,1) as Token
       ,CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.String,IndexNum + 1,1) = 's' THEN t.CharCount + 1 ELSE 0 END AS CharCount
    FROM
       #TempTable s
       INNER JOIN cteTokens t
       ON s.String = t.String
       AND LENGTH(s.String) >= t.IndexNum + 1
)

SELECT
    String
    ,MAX(CharCount)
FROM
    cteTokens
GROUP BY
    String
;
```

And Here is a SQL-Server Version

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (String VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (String) VALUES ('mississsipisssss')
INSERT INTO #TempTable (String) VALUES ('ssasdfs')

;WITH cteTokens (String, IndexNum, Token, CharCount) AS  (
    SELECT
       t.String
       ,1 as IndexNum
       ,SUBSTRING(t.String,1,1) as Token
       ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.String,1,1) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As CharCount
    FROM
       #TempTable t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.String
       ,IndexNum + 1 as IndexNum
       ,SUBSTRING(t.String,IndexNum + 1,1) as Token
       ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.String,IndexNum + 1,1) = 's' THEN t.CharCount + 1 ELSE 0 END As CharCount
    FROM
       #TempTable s
       INNER JOIN cteTokens t
       ON s.String = t.String
       AND LEN(s.String) >= t.IndexNum + 1
)

SELECT
    String
    ,MAX(CharCount)
FROM
    cteTokens
GROUP BY
    String
```

It is a `Recursive Common Table Expression [CTE]` that splits the string into character tokens in order of Index Position and tests to see if they are the character you desire.  If the token is the character then it builds on the count from the previous token if is character so all you have to do is take the `MAX()` of the result and you have your answer.

Comment: This will fail, at least in Oracle. There is no FROM clause in the first CTE, Oracle does not have a SUBSTRING function (there is a SUBSTR function), the recursive CTE must have a column alias list...   Did you test the query in any of the RDBMS's? Where it compiled without errors and gave the correct answer? In any case, the post is clearly tagged as Oracle and this has three Oracle errors I can see with the naked eye in a few seconds. Clear demerit.

Comment: some of the comment was useful and I have updated my answer.  yes this works and it was tested.  By all means steel the idea and clean up for oracle syntax

Comment: It was tested in the form you posted initially? And it worked? Really?

Comment: how about being constructive, yes it was tested in an RDBMs that has same recursive cte capabilities of Oracle and it worked as the original edit.  Test it yourself and please do take a look at the oracle version and feel free to edit the answer to clean it up I don't have access to oracle and I don't write a lot against oracle so I am sure that an experienced oracle guru could add some syntax suggestions

Comment: There is only one syntax error left, Oracle's length function is LENGTH. Otherwise the recursive CTE solution is working (at least applied to one input string at a time; it would need to be adapted to work on strings in a table column).

Comment: My point is, if the OP says Oracle, either post a solution that works in Oracle, or perhaps post one that works in MySQL or SQL Server or whatever as "this is something that works in ... and perhaps can be adapted for Oracle" - that's not what you said before you edited your post. The original question was clearly tagged Oracle.

Comment: your point was masked by your method and tone.  And unfortunately instead of helping the OP use a valid technique by constructively providing feedback and edit suggestions it provided confusion and more time to obtain an answer.  I do need to pay more attention to looking at syntax when it comes to oracle issues and I will do so

Answer (score 1):

Here is a standard solution using a hierarchical query. The CASE expression in the outer query is needed to give the answer "null" when the input string is "null" (otherwise the answer would be 0, and it shouldn't be). I didn't add an ORDER BY clause - you can do so if needed. Good luck!

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select 'mississsipisssss' from dual union all
       select null               from dual union all
       select 'stress'           from dual union all
       select 'alphabeta'        from dual
     ),
     prep ( str, lvl ) as (
     select str, level
     from   inputs
     connect by  prior str = str
             and prior sys_guid() is not null
             and regexp_instr(str, 's{' || to_char(level-1) || '}') != 0
     )
select   str, case when str is not null then max(lvl) - 1 end as max_len
from     prep
group by str
;


STR                 MAX_LEN
---------------- ----------
(null)               (null)
alphabeta                 0
stress                    2
mississsipisssss          5

4 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an operation well supported by databases, although Postres definitely has functionality in this area.

If you know there is some limit on the number of substrings of "s"s, then you could do something like this:

```
select greatest(coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 1)), 0),
                coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 2)), 0),
                coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 3)), 0),
                coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 4)), 0),
                coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 5)), 0),
                coalesce(length(regexp(substr(string, '[s]+', 1, 6)), 0)
               )
```

This would find the first 6 substrings and then calculate the maximum length.

The alternative is essentially to split the string yourself using `connect by` or a recursive CTE.  However, the above might be sufficient.